# How to use an extractor with from_request

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have the following route handler, which sends a 400 BAD REQUEST in case of parse error in FormData.

```
#[post("/newsletter")]
pub async fn publish_newsletter(
    form: web::Form<FormData>,
    ...
) -> Result<HttpResponse, PublishError> {
    ...
}
```

To provide better UX, I want to opt out of this behavior. I'd like to redirect the user to the same page and display the error as a flash message.

But I can't seem to figure out how to extract FormData using [Form::from_request](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.FromRequest.html#tymethod.from_request)

I have tried using HttpRequest and web::dev::Payload extractors:

```rust
#[post("/newsletter")]
pub async fn publish_newsletter(
    ...
    req: HttpRequest,
    mut payload: dev::Payload,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, PublishError> {
    let form: web::Form<FormData> = match web::Form::from_request(&req, &mut payload).await {
        Ok(data) => data,
        Err(e) => {
            // send flash message
            // redirect to same page
            return Ok(see_other("/newsletter"));
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

But ultimately I'm faced with this error:

```
the trait bound `actix_web::dev::Payload: FromRequest` is not satisfied
```

Comment: `Form<T>` just requires `T: Deserialize`. See https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Form.html

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi Yes, the Form extractor as a parameter works fine. But I'd like to extract it inside the handler *body*, so I can react differently in case of error. I've updated the post to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it in the following way:

```rust
#[post("/newsletter")]
pub async fn publish_newsletter(
    form: Result<web::Form<FormData>, actix_web::Error>,
    ...
) -> Result<HttpResponse, PublishError> {
    let form = match form {
        Ok(form) => form,
        Err(e) => return Ok(send_flash_message_and_redirect(e, "/newsletter")),
    };
    ...
}
```

Shoutout to the helpful folks at Actix Web [Discord](https://discord.gg/NWpN5mmg3x).